# How to configure the same value in all cells in row

Tags: usability, tables

I have a table in which I want to set a value for an entire row. In excel and such, after you enter a value in one cell you can copy it (expand but "pulling" the cell edge) to other cells.
Do you have examples of other options for entering a value for all cells in a row?
Could be additional cell that appears, action that appears on hover, or anything else.

Thanks.

Comment: The current behavior is hidden and not standard, you select the entire row, the last cell is editable, type a value and hit enter. Then the value is copied to all cells in the row.

Excel copt functionality cannot be implemented. 

Looking for an alternative.

Comment: How often you need to do this? Is this important functionality or just needed from time to time?

Answer (score 0):

one idea pops to my mind, since you state, that the whole row should be updated you could place a CTA on each row. this could be text or icon, but text would be more clear. When the CTA is clicked, show a popup or similar.

[image]

[image]